# ANTLR grammar not handling my "not" operator correctly

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr3

I am trying to parse a small expression language (I didn't define the language, from a vendor) and everything is fine until I try to use the not operator, which is a tilde in this language.

My grammar has been heavily influenced by these two links (aka shameless cut and pasting):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/sota_expression_evaluator.aspx http://www.alittlemadness.com/2006/06/05/antlr-by-example-part-1-the-language

The language consists of three expression types that can be used with and, or, not operators and parenthesis change precedence. Expressions are:

```
Skill("name") > some_number (can also be <, >=, <=,  =, !=)
SkillExists("name")
LoggedIn("name") (this one can also have name@name)
```

This input works fine:

```
Skill("somename") > 1 | (LoggedIn("somename") & SkillExists("othername"))
```

However, as soon as I try to use the not operator I get NoViableAltException. I can't figure out why. I have compared my grammar to the ECalc.g one at the codeproject.com link and they seem to match, there must be some subtle difference I can't see. Fails:

```
Skill("somename") < 10 ~ SkillExists("othername")
```

My Grammar:

```
grammar UserAttribute;

options {
output=AST;
ASTLabelType=CommonTree;
}

tokens {
SKILL = 'Skill' ;
SKILL_EXISTS = 'SkillExists' ;
LOGGED_IN = 'LoggedIn';
GT = '>';
LT = '<';
LTE = '<=';
GTE = '>=';
EQUALS = '=';
NOT_EQUALS = '!=';  
AND = '&';
OR = '|' ;
NOT = '~';
LPAREN   = '(';
RPAREN = ')';
QUOTE = '"';
AT = '@';       
}

/*------------------------------------------------------------------
 * PARSER RULES
 *------------------------------------------------------------------*/  
expression : orexpression EOF!; 
orexpression    : andexpression (OR^ andexpression)*;
andexpression   : notexpression (AND^ notexpression)*;  
notexpression : primaryexpression | NOT^ primaryexpression;
primaryexpression : term | LPAREN! orexpression RPAREN!;
term    : skill_exists | skill | logged_in;
skill_exists    : SKILL_EXISTS LPAREN QUOTE NAME QUOTE RPAREN;
logged_in : LOGGED_IN LPAREN QUOTE NAME (AT NAME)? QUOTE RPAREN;
skill:  SKILL LPAREN QUOTE NAME QUOTE RPAREN ((GT | LT| LTE | GTE | EQUALS | NOT_EQUALS)? NUMBER*)?;

/*------------------------------------------------------------------
 * LEXER RULES
 *------------------------------------------------------------------*/
NAME    : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '_')+;
NUMBER  : ('0'..'9')+ ;
WHITESPACE : ( '\t' | ' ' | '\r' | '\n'| '\u000C' )+    { $channel = HIDDEN; } ;
```

Comment: But how should `Skill("somename") < 10 ~ SkillExists("othername")` be parsed? I assume `Skill("somename") < 10` is a `skill` expression and `~ SkillExists("othername")` is a `notexpression`. But no rule matches  a `skill` followed by a `notexpression`, right?

Comment: Both Skill("somename") < 10 and SkillExists("othername") are primary expressions, the notexpression lets the NOT token come before any primary expression. Does that answer your question? 

I am a ANTLR newbie so it is possible my grammar is so fundamentally flawed it is beyond hope. Although I am pretty sure I understand it and I think I am pretty close.

Comment: no not really, you were wondering why `Skill("somename") < 10 ~ SkillExists("othername")` failed, which isn't surprising to me: it should fail. I tried to explain this in my first remark of my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have 2 remarks:

### 1

Since you're parsing single expressions (`expression : orexpression EOF!;`), the input `"Skill("somename") < 10 ~ SkillExists("othername")"` is not only invalid in your grammar, but it's invalid in terms of any expression parser (I know of). A `notexpression` only takes a "right-hand-side" expression, so `~ SkillExists("othername")` is a single expression and `Skill("somename") < 10` is also a single expression. But in between those two single expression, there's no `OR` or `AND` operator. It would be the same as evaluating the expression `true false` instead of `true | false` or `true and false`.

In short, your grammar disallows:

```
Skill("somename") < 10 ~ SkillExists("othername")
```

but allows for:

```
Skill("somename") < 10 & SkillExists("othername")
```

which seems logical to me.

### 2

I don't quite understand your `skill` rule (which is ambiguous, btw):

```
skill
 : SKILL LPAREN QUOTE NAME QUOTE RPAREN 
     ((GT | LT| LTE | GTE | EQUALS | NOT_EQUALS)? NUMBER*)?
 ;
```

This means that the operator is optional and there can be zero or more numbers at the end. This means that the following input are all valid:

- `Skill("foo") = 10 20`
- `Skill("foo") 10 20 30`
- `Skill("foo") <`

Perhaps you meant:

```
skill
 : SKILL LPAREN QUOTE NAME QUOTE RPAREN 
     ((GT | LT| LTE | GTE | EQUALS | NOT_EQUALS)^ NUMBER)?
 ;
```

instead? (the `?` becomes a `^` and the `*` is removed)

If I only change that rule and parse the input:

```
Skill("somename") < 10 & SkillExists("othername")
```

the following AST is created:

[image]

*(as you can see, the AST needs to be better formed: i.e. you need some rewrite rules in your `skill_exists`, `logged_in` and `skill` rules)*

---

EDIT

and if you want successive expressions to have implied `AND` tokens in between, do something like this:

```
grammar UserAttribute;

...
tokens {
...
I_AND;     // <- added a token without any text (imaginary token)
AND = '&';
...
}

andexpression
  :  (notexpression -> notexpression) (AND? notexpression -> ^(I_AND $andexpression notexpression))*
  ;  

...
```

As you can see, since the `AND` is now optional, it cannot be used inside a rewrite rule, but you'll have to use the imaginary token `I_AND`.

If you now parse the input:

```
Skill("somename") < 10 ~ SkillExists("othername")
```

you will get the following AST:

[image]

Comment: Ok, you gave me lots of information and so far it all makes sense! Thanks! I knew there was something odd about the vendors not operator but couldn't put my finger on it, you articulated it quite well. Their expression language allows "true ~false" whereas in terms of any other language you would write this "true && !false". So my grammar actually does need to support "true ~false" with no other operator in between. (On a side note, that makes me wonder how to interpret that, is it an implied "and"...hmm).

Comment: Also, the ? in the skill rule is a remnant of a refactor gone awry. You are correct I don't need that, thanks for pointing that out! (same with the * after number, I did have skill, skill exists, and loggedin as one rule a few days ago, but refactored them out to their own rules and didn't adequately check my rules after the refactor)

Comment: I have never heard of rewrite rules (total newbie here) but I have found a wiki page on them on the antler wiki...reading about them now

Comment: Rewrite rules are similar to the inline `^` (AST root) and `!` (exclude from AST) operators you've already used.

Comment: @Michael, I added a small example of how to handle "implied `AND`'s". See the EDIT.

Comment: Ok, apparently I based my grammar on a typo in some vendor documentation. You do in fact need an intermediate logical operator before the not. So

    Skill("name") > 10 & ~Skill("othername") is the correct syntax. Sigh. That makes much more sense too.

Comment: @Michael, okay, then you needn't change the `andexpression`.